# Синонім до слова "вогненебезпечно"

Tags: вибір-слова

Як на мене слово "вогненебезпечно" — калька з російської і до того ж досить недолуга через збіг "нене" всередині слова.

Чи є якийсь синонім, який можна було б писати на парканах навколо місць із небезпекою пожежі (газові споруди, автозаправки і т.і.)?

[Worldwidedictionary](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) пропонує такі синоніми до слова "вогненебезпечний": *легкозаймистий, займистий, палахкий*. Але як можна повідомити присутніх, що в певному місці не треба користуватися відкритим вогнем, при цьому уникаючи використання слова *"вогненебезпечно"*?

Comment: *Пожежонебезпечний*?

Comment: Це вже краще (хоча б -нене- не стирчить), але наскільки взагалі такі кентаври властиві українській мові?

Comment: Потребує поглибленого дослідження і, мабуть, переформулювання запитання) Це перше, що спало на думку. По-перше, дійсно, без *не-не*. По-друге, більш широке в контекстуальному застосуванні. Тобто, *пожежонебезпечними* можуть бути як речовина, так і  ситуація, період тощо, на противагу *легкозаймистому*, наприклад.

Comment: Поправив *місті→місці*, [*оточуючих→присутніх*](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8F/) і трошки wording для більшої чіткості. Feel free to rollback, якщо це не те, що малося на увазі.

Comment: *Невогнебезпечний*?

Comment: Може спробувати замінити слово "небезпека" на схожий синонім "загроза"? Наприклад, вогнезагрозливий, вогнева загроза, вогнезагрожений.

Comment: Або використовувати два слова, наприклад, "ризик займання", "ризик пожежі"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [ВОГНЕНЕБЕЗПЕ́ЧНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/voghnenebezpechnyj), а, е.
>   **Небезпечний щодо пожежі; легкозаймистий**. *При поводженні з бензином необхідно пам'ятати, що він дуже вогненебезпечний* (Підручник
>   шофера.., 1960, 323).

Окрім СУМ, це слово знаходимо й на [Українському лінгвістичному порталі](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду НАН України та у нормативних документах - [сайт ВРУ](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/main).

У СУМ ***`вогненебезпечний`*** тлумачиться через *`небезпеку щодо пожежі`* або *`легкозаймистість`*.

> [ЛЕГКОЗАЙМИ́СТИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/leghkozajmystyj), а, е. **Який
>   легко займається**. *Облицювання печей листовою сталлю обов'язкове в
>   приміщеннях, де в повітрі можуть бути легкозаймисті гази* (Довідник
>   сільського будівельника, 1956, 456).

І хоч через тлумачення вищезгаданих синонімів це неочевидно, але з прикладів вживання (через Google пошук) можна дійти висновку, що [***`легкозаймистий`***](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&oq=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l2.5985j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), як і *`займистий`* і *`палахкий`*, має вужче значення, адже може стосуватися речовини, матеріалу, предмету тощо, в той час як [***`вогненебезпечний`***](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&oq=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l2.5985j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&start=0) має ширші контекстуальні можливості, бо також може характеризувати ситуацію, період, роботи, бізнес і т.і.

Спробуємо підібрати синоніми, враховуючи побажання автора запитання та орієнтуючись на значення самого слова ***`вогненебезпечний`***, яке пояснюється як *`небезпечний щодо пожежі`*.

Перше, що спадає на думку, це, звісно, ***`пожежонебезпечний`***. І хоч цього прикметника немає в СУМ, та він є на [Українському лінгвістичному порталі](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду НАНУ.

Окрім цього, ***`пожежонебезпечний`*** - у досить широкому загальному вжитку (згідно з [Google search](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&oq=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l2.5985j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)), а також закріплений у нормативних документах  [сайт ВРУ](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/main).

Як варіант можу запропонувати ***`вибухонебезпечний`*** (зрозуміло, тільки в певному контексті), що теж можна знайти на [Українському лінгвістичному порталі](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду НАНУ. Вживання також підтверджується результатами [пошуку Google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&oq=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l2.5985j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) та нормативкою на [сайті ВРУ](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/main).

Стосовно власне складних слів, то, щоб не обтяжувати відповідь, зазначу, що такий спосіб словотворення цілком характерний для української мови. Таким чином утворюються майже усі частини мови, хіба що окрім дієслів.  [Правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#prasklad) містить цілий розділ, присвячений складним словам. Зустрічаються й значно кострубатіші й менш милозвучні утворення, аніж ***`вогненебезпечний`*** :) Наприклад, в нормативних документах ([сайт ВРУ](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/main)) досить розповсюджений складний прикметник ***`вибухопожежонебезпечний`***.